# Arrange the Bar color based on Column name in Matplotlib Bar Chart

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I am working on a bar chart using Matplotlib,

The snippet is given below for reference

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import pandas as pd 

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = 'Ubuntu'
plt.rcParams['font.monospace'] = 'Ubuntu Mono'
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 10
plt.rcParams['axes.labelweight'] = 'bold'
plt.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 10
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10
plt.rcParams['figure.titlesize'] = 12

current_date = datetime.date.today()
project_task = [{'Project': u'Adding Numbers', 'Stage': u'Resolved'}, {'Project': u'Adding Numbers', 'Stage': u'In Progress'},
                {'Project': u'Adding Numbers', 'Stage': u'In Progress'},{'Project': u'Adding Numbers', 'Stage': u'In Progress'},
                {'Project': u'PMS', 'Stage': u'Resolved'}, {'Project': u'PMS', 'Stage': u'Pending'}, {'Project': u'Adding Numbers', 'Stage': u'In Progress'},
                {'Project': u'Adding Numbers', 'Stage': u'Pending'}, {'Project': u'PMS', 'Stage': u'In Progress'}, {'Project': u'Ajax PMS', 'Stage': u'Resolved'},
                {'Project': u'PMS', 'Stage': u'In Progress'}, {'Project': u'PMS', 'Stage': u'Resolved'}, {'Project': u'PMS', 'Stage': u'In Progress'},
                {'Project': u'PMS', 'Stage': u'In Progress'}]
color_list = ['#007256','#f6c700','#0067a7','#964f8e','#bd1e24','#e97600','#967d46']
data_frame_task = pd.DataFrame(project_task)
if not data_frame_task.empty:
    task_frame = pd.pivot_table(data_frame_task, index='Project', columns='Stage', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
    print task_frame
    task = task_frame.plot(kind="bar",stacked=True,width=0.1,color=color)
    plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
    plt.savefig("/tmp/" + str(current_date) + " Task.png", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=75)
```

The above code produce the fig in the below format[image]

But I like to specify the bar color based on stage name:
**for example** In progress means yellow, Resolved means green,
Pending means red.

1. My question is how to fix that color list in my bar chart image.
2. If a new stage is introduce it should take random color.

**EDIT ONE**
***I Solved by the following way;*** (Not satisfied)

```
data_frame_task = pd.DataFrame(project_task)
        if not data_frame_task.empty:
            task_frame = pd.pivot_table(data_frame_task, index='Project', columns='Stage', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
            task_list = task_frame.columns.tolist()
            color_list = []
            for task in task_list:
                if task == "Blocked":
                    color_list.append("#FF0000")
                elif task == "In Progress":
                    color_list.append('#FFA500')
                elif task == "Pending":
                    color_list.append("#DB7093")
                elif task == "Reopen":
                    color_list.append('#0000FF')
                elif task == "Resolved":
                    color_list.append('#008000')
                else:
                    color_list.append('#FFFFFF')
            task_frame.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, width=0.5,color=color_list)
            plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
            plt.savefig("/tmp/" + str(current_date) + " Task.png", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0, dpi=75)
```

**Note** This is not the pythonic way 
  Any better answer is appreciated